# function in rootscope, can't access rootscope variable

Tags: angularjs

In my app.run I have an function which get some text from an global variable from an other file. In that variable there are some keywords with an language attribute, which allows me to only get the requested text and filter out the right language.

I made an function for that but I can't get access the `$rootScope.language` variable in that function which I need for getting the right text.

```
function getTourTranslation(key){
    console.log("getTourTranslation", key);
    var lang = $rootScope.language;
    var step = _.get(steps, key);
    return step[lang]
}
```

So language is undefined, and so `$rootScope.language` is, but the variable exists and contains the right language key for the current language on the site. How can I get the content of that variabele without passing the language as variable into the function?

I also tried as `$rootScope.getTourTranslation = function(key)` but no luck

### edit:

This is how the language variable is filled. We use angular-translate, so that is the $translate service. This code is placed above the `getTourTranslation` function.

```
$rootScope.changeLanguage = function (langKey) {
    if(langKey){
        if(langKey.length == 2) {
            $translate.use(langKey.toLowerCase()+"_"+langKey.toUpperCase());
            $rootScope.language = langKey;
        } else if(langKey.length == 5) {
            $translate.use(langKey);
            $rootScope.language = langKey.substring(0,2);
        }
    }
};

$rootScope.$on('$translateChangeSuccess', function () {
    if($translate.use()){
        $rootScope.language = $translate.use().substring(0,2);
        if($state.$current && !$state.$current.self.abstract) {
            $state.reload();
        }
    }
});
$rootScope.changeLanguage($translate.use());
```

Comment: Can you show the `$rootScope.language` code?

Comment: I have added it to the question @chsdk

Comment: But have you initialized `$rootScope.language`in the app scope outside your  functions?

Comment: No, that is also in the run section. the `getTourTranslation` function is beneath that code.

Comment: For example, in another function `$rootScope.test = function(){ console.log($rootScope.language); }` I get the active language,

Comment: Ok, I got it. So the problem is only with `getTourTranslation`function?

Comment: Yes, that's true.

Comment: hi @NVO, can you create a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) of your issue?. so that it is easy to debug

Comment: @SunilLama hmm I have created an plunkr, but everything is working fine there, so there must be an difference in my code.. 
https://embed.plnkr.co/o16dpI/

Comment: First of all that is not possible that variabe defined on $rootScope lvl is not available withing the same context.

I can imagine only one case: it calls `getTourTranslation` so early so none of `changeLanguage` or `$translateChangeSuccess` handlers ran

Comment: @BotanMan yeah, found it. It was indeed an call on $rootScope.language before it was initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible that variable defined on `$rootScope` is not available withing the same context.

I can imagine only one case: 
it calls `getTourTranslation` so early so none of `changeLanguage` or `$translateChangeSuccess` handler ran

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, that `$rootScope.language` was called before it was initialized.

So, I placed the call to the `getTourTranslation()` function in an function which is called after firing an button. So, the right variables are now only initialized when they are needed instead of always.

So, I fixed two things, and that all based on the comment from @BotanMan